# Arithmetic for converting index to coordinates just returns index

Tags: objective-c, ios, math

I have a grid of images, like a 2D tile set. This method is supposed to give me the image from the tile set when I just give the the tile index.

Can anyone see where my math is screwed up? Currently this function just gives me `n` and `n.(random decimal)` for the `x` and `y`.

```
- (CGImageRef)tileFromTileset:(int)gid {
    CGImageRef tile;
    CGPoint point;
    CGFloat fGid = (CGFloat)gid;
    point.x = fmodf(fGid, tileSource.size.width);
    point.y = (fGid - (fmod(fGid, tileSource.size.width)) / (tileSource.size.width) + 1);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
    tile = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([tileSource CGImage], CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, kTileWidth, kTileHeight));
    return tile;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a simple error of units. At the moment, you're dividing a number representing an index by a number representing a coordinate; the unit that you end up with is therefore "index per coordinate".* What you want, though, is just coordinate units.

The assignment to `point.x` should therefore be:

```
point.x = fmodf(fGid * kTileWidth, tileSource.size.width);
```

That is, the tile index (units: "index"), multiplied by the width of one tile (units: "coordinates per index"), gives you its location if this were a single row of tiles (units: "coordinates"). Taking the remainder after dividing by the actual width of a row of tiles gives you the correct x coordinate.

For `point.y`, you need the quotient of the same calculation:

```
point.y = trunc(fGid * kTileWidth / tileSouce.size.width) * kTileHeight;
```

The index, multiplied by the width of a tile, divided by the width of a row, tells you how many rows are completed at that index; multiply by the height of a tile to get the coordinate.

This might be even clearer with one more constant, `kNumTilesInRow`:

```
point.x = (gid % kNumTilesInRow) * kTileWidth;
point.y = (gid / kNumTilesInRow) * kTileHeight;
```

---

*You keep getting `n` back because, for `abs(n) < abs(m)`, `n % m` always equals `n`.

Comment: I don't think i could make kNumTilesInRow though, because i'm wanting it to be flexible. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move a parenthesis.

Assuming a 3 x 3 layout as follows:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

And you call this passing a 7, here's what I see:

```
- (CGImageRef)tileFromTileset:(int)gid  {  // 7
    CGImageRef tile;
    CGPoint point;
    CGFloat fGid = (CGFloat)gid;  // 7
    point.x = fmodf(fGid, tileSource.size.width);  // x= 7 % 3, so x=1

    // y= (7 - 1 / 3 + 1), so y= 7.6666666  
    point.y = (fGid - (fmod(fGid, tileSource.size.width)) / (tileSource.size.width) + 1); 

    // Try this instead of the above
    // y = ((7 - 1) / 3 + 1), so y=3
    //  point.y = ((fGid - fmod(fGid, tileSource.size.width)) / (tileSource.size.width) + 1); 

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
    tile = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([tileSource CGImage], CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, kTileWidth, kTileHeight));
    return tile;
```